# Mono Migration Analyzer: What are all of the command line switches?

Tags: mono, moma

So I'm looking here and I see the command line switches. http://mono-project.com/Command_Line_MoMA

This is what I see as the total amount of switches from the site:

> MoMA.exe --nogui --out C:\app\momareport\report.html C:\app\myapp.exe

One thing I see is the submit.xml going to a place I don't want during my automated build. Since it is a generated file, I want to change where it goes. Is there a switch for that?

Also, what are all of the switches for it?

If there is not a switch for moving the submit.xml to a reporting location, please consider it for future versions.

EDIT: The argument --help does not work. I tried that and a host of others to try to get some dialog from MoMA on the command line. I'm on Windows to help alleviate any confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are the only command line switches supported by MoMA.  You can see the code [here](http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/moma/Program.cs?view=markup).

"MoMA.exe --help" does not work because MoMA is compiled as a winforms application so that the command window is not shown.  As a result, MoMA disconnects from the command window, and therefore things like Console.WriteLine will not work.

To answer your actual question, there is currently not a way to change where the .xml file gets put.

Comment: I don't really have any plans to add any at the moment.  Those were contributed by some people who wanted to run MoMA in their automated build.  Aside from the placement of the .xml report already mentioned, are there any others you would like to see?

Comment: That was really the only one. I just didn't want a file changing every time in source. But I can set it to ignore for now.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try:

```
MoMA.exe --help
```

On Linux, there should also be a manpage.

If you can't find the feature, and want to submit it to Mono, you'll want to go via the [Bugzilla page](https://bugzilla.novell.com/index.cgi).

Comment: Perhaps this is because I am running from Windows?

Comment: Hrmm, that's odd. Try just running `moma` without any args?